# Why won't my datatable populate

Tags: c#, excel, gridview, import

I have searched a long time and I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

I have a web app that uploads a spreadsheet (verified it works) and is supposed to parse the spreadsheet and populate a GridView. Seems simple enough, but it won't display the data.

The spreadsheet I'm testing with (as an upload; the upload works as expected) is a simple single tab spreadsheet with everything boring vanilla... three columns with column names with one row of data (two populated rows total, destined to be expanded once this thing works). The tab name is the `CRPRList` used in the `OleDbDataAdapter` below.

I'm getting no errors on the page, just the GridView does not populate.

Here's the GridView in ASP.net:

```
<asp:GridView ID="TopicsTbl" runat="server" 
     AllowSorting="False" 
     AllowPaging="False" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="False">
     <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField HeaderText="CR" DataField="CR" />
         <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PR" DataField="PR" />
         <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Summary" DataField="Summary" />
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I've got it down to the following code. What I mean by that is that I've tested everything down to this. No errors and things seem to work as expected... except the GridView won't populate:

```
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [CRPRList$]", XLSConnect);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    adapter.Fill(ds, "CRPRList");

    DataTable data = ds.Tables["CRPRList"];
    TopicsTbl.DataSource = data;
```

The `XLSConnect` string will depend on wether or not the file is xls or xlsx:

```
   string strConn;
    if (fileType.ToLower() == "xls" || fileType.ToLower() == "xlsx") {
        strConn = (fileType == "xlsx") ? string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0\"", filePath) : string.Format("Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0\"", filePath);

        XLSConnect = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
        return true;
    } else return false; //throw new Exception("file extension is not registering");
```

What am I missing? Or am I doing something wrong?

I'm guessing my GridView is not set up right, or my spreadsheet parsing understanding is not complete... could be way off though!

Thanks

Comment: `Jimmy` do you really need this in this line of code `CRPRList" ` adapter.Fill(ds, "CRPRList");`..?

Comment: Hmmm... removing it does not fix the issue. I confess that performing this kind of function is new to me. Without it, how does `ds` get populated with the data from adapter?

Comment: look at the answer I posted also can you verify that the `Select` statement works running it in your database..? is `XLSConnect` a valid connection string also can you show the connection string or at least verify on your end that it at least connect to the database

Comment: `Jimmy` look at this link it should be very helpful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32370/Import-Excel-File-to-DataSet

Comment: Thanks, that's one I hadn't seen yet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind the data:

```
DataTable data = ds.Tables[0];
TopicsTbl.DataSource = data;
TopicsTbl.DataBind();
```

Comment: I think this is getting closer... but still, the data won't appear. I've tried this variation before.

Comment: This was it! All I had to do was change the "CRPRList" to `0`. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

you can try something simple like this Jimmy

```
using (var data = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [CRPRList$]", XLSConnect))
{
    var table = new DataTable();
    data.Fill(table);
    TopicsTbl.DataSource = data;
    TopicsTbl.DataBind();
};
```

Comment: Thanks DJ but this won't even compile. `OleDbDataAdapter` is a type being used like a var.

Comment: Typo sorry.. let me edit real quick, you can recompile with the change and it will work.. sorry I was using `SqlDataAdapter` in my current code sorry for the initial Typo

Comment: Thanks again... getting closer! I have a new error: "Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource." I'm looking it up

Comment: How about this Try it using one DataSource in the connection string then see if it works using each one separately ..the code I have also you can change the `table = new DataTable` and try doing it with `table = new DataSet`